# How to use snowpack with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, snowpack

I recently got to know about snowpack and it's advantages but the thing is all the available tutorials are on how to make a react app with snowpack but **I wanted to use it with react-native**. I saw that expo uses webpack does that mean we can use snowpack instead by initializing a bare react-native app. Any help would be appreciated (like link of any tutorial).

**NOTE :**
I did get a github discussion saying the author doesn't have enough knowledge about react-native in particular. Does that mean he will have to do some additional work for supporting react-native?

Comment: I am also searching about it

Comment: @vishawnathkokare if you ever managed to find it please add it as an answer here